# How to fix UrlGenerationError Missing Required Key [:quid] error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to setup a payment process through stripe for teachers, which I called Mentor.

The process consists of redirecting students, once they added card details in, to a page pickup where they would be able to download the content. For some reason it says that there is a key[:quid] missing.

Here is my transaction controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    mentor =  Mentor.find_by!(slug: params[:slug])
    token = params[:stripeToken]

    begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        :card   => token,
        :amount      => (mentor.price * 100).floor,
        :description => current_user.email,
        :currency    => 'gbp'
        )

        @sale = mentor.sales.create(email_user: current_user.email)
        redirect_to pickup_url(guid: @sale.guid)

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        @error = e
        redirect_to mentor_path(mentor), notice: @error
    end

end

def pickup
    @sale = Sale.find_by!(guid: params[:guid])
    @mentor = @sale.mentor
end
```

end

Here is the sale.rb:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
before_create :generate_guid
belongs_to :mentor

private
    def generate_guid
        self.guid = SecureRandom.uuid()
    end
end
```

An here is the summary of the error:

[The error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIbhj.png)

Comment: Please post your `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Show us the `routes.rb`. Looks like it is a type `quid` and `guid`.

Comment: @Зелёный is right – wherever the `pickup` route is defined in your `config/routes.rb` file you will probably find that you have typed `quid` instead of `guid`. Change this, restart your server and try again!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Don't use an image to show us errors, data or code. Instead, copy and paste the error into your question, formatting it appropriately. Links rot then break, resulting in essential information that is missing. Also the search engines can't index the image resulting in less visibility of your question when other search for similar solutions. Don't use salutations ("hi I'm a beginner") or valedictions ("thanks") or signatures ("Lilija"). SO isn't a discussion list, it's a reference site. Keep it concise and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

```
@sale = mentor.sales.create(email_user: current_user.email)
redirect_to pickup_url(quid: @sale.guid)
```

Comment: While this might work, the problem has most likely originated with a typo – it's probably a better idea to fix the original typo instead of perpetuating it throughout the app like this.

Comment: Don't toss out code, instead explain _why_ the code is usable and fixes the problem. We want to educate the OP so they understand how to fix it if they encounter the problem again, and hopefully then can help others.